# Unicode text from SQLite database seems to be broken

Tags: sqlite, haskell, unicode, utf-8

I'm using  http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sqlite-0.5.2.2 for binding to SQLite database. Inside *.db file there is text in UTF-8 encoding, I can assure this in text editor and sqlite CLI tool.

When connecting to database and retrieving data - the text content is broken. The simple test goes below:

```
import qualified Database.SQLite as SQL
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
import System.IO

buildSkypeMessages dbh = 
  (go <$> (SQL.execStatement dbh "select chatname,author,timestamp,body_xml from messages order by chatname, timestamp")) >>=
  writeIt
  where
    writeIt content = withFile "test.txt" WriteMode (\handle -> mapM_ (\(c:a:t:[]) -> hPutStrLn handle c) content)
    go (Left msg) = fail msg
    go (Right rows) = map f $ concat rows
      where
        f' (("chatname",SQL.Text chatname):
            ("author",SQL.Text author):
            ("timestamp",SQL.Int timestamp):
            r) = ([chatname, author], r)
        f xs = let (partEntry, (item:_)) = f' xs
               in case item of
                 ("body_xml",SQL.Text v) -> v:partEntry
                 ("body_xml",SQL.Null)   -> "":partEntry
        escape (_,SQL.Text v) = v
        escape (_,SQL.Null) = ""
        escape (_,SQL.Int v) = show v
```

What may be wrong there? Am I missing something with Sqlite or with Haskell I/O and encodings?

Comment: One place this can go wrong is in writing the file: GHC will use your current locale to choose the default encoding for this operation. You can test whether this is the problem by calling [hSetEncoding](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/System-IO.html#v:hSetEncoding).

Comment: @DanielWagner my current locale is en_US.UTF-8, so it shouldn't be the case. Data in text file looks like double-encoded to utf-8

Comment: @DanielWagner setting binary mode helped. Thanks!

Comment: In that case, I suspect that what you are getting out of the SQL database is not a `String`, but a sequence of bytes incorrectly jammed into the type `String`. You should decode it manually before using it.

Comment: I hope someone will actually put an answer up :)

Comment: @XTL ok, I explained what solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem was not related to SQLite bindings but to String handling in Haskell. What solved the problem - invoking hSetBinaryMode on handle before putting data on it:

```
writeIt content = withFile "test.txt" WriteMode (\handle -> hSetBinaryMode handle True >> mapM_ (\(c:a:t:[]) -> hPutStrLn handle c) content)
```